# adding a while statement to my python twitter bot

Tags: python, twitter, bots

I'm working on a python twitter script. So far it works great, but I need to add a while statement to limit the number of unfollows (api calls) to less than 100. I have been working on this all day and I admit I'm new to python, I may be missing something simple but I have tried a handful of variations to no avail.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tweepy
from keys import keys

SCREEN_NAME = keys['screen_name']
CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
followers = api.followers_ids(SCREEN_NAME)
friends = api.friends_ids(SCREEN_NAME)
for f in friends:
    if f not in followers:
        print "Unfollow {0}?".format(api.get_user(f).screen_name)
if raw_input("Y/N?") == 'y' or 'Y':
    api.destroy_friendship(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an unfollow counter and increment that counter when you make an unfollow call.  Then check if the counter is less than 100 in addition to the 'y' answer.

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

...code before for loop here...
unfollows = 0
for f in friends:
    if f not in followers:
        print "Unfollow {0}?".format(api.get_user(f).screen_name)
        input = raw_input("Y/N?")
        if (unfollows < 100) and (input == 'y' or input 'Y'):
            api.destroy_friendship(f)
            unfollows += 1
```

Comment: this makes it so that i have to push 'y' after every iteration...and my original code does them all at once... how would I write this so that it asks me after 99 selections to unfollow???

Comment: It looks like you're prompting if you want to unfollow the specific user, is that correct?  If so, you need to press 'y' each time.  Otherwise, it will unfollow everyone it encounters, as long as unfollows < 100.